# Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json error

Tags: mvvmcross

I just started learning PCL in xamarin and I have been going over the MvvmCross tutorial and i cant find why i keep getting this error 
No overload for method 'EnsureLoaded' takes 1 arguments:

```
protected override IMvxNavigationSerializer CreateNavigationSerializer()
        {
            Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded(true);
            return new MvxJsonNavigationSerializer();
        }
```

I installed the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json and all the other reffereces:

can some help please thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know it doesn't need any arguments at all, so try just

```
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
```